# Trying to pause/stop a jquery css behaviour

Tags: jquery, loops

I want the visibility:visible to stay, where currently it flashes momentarily then disappears.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subscribe').click(function(e) {
        $('#joinThanks').css('visibility', 'visible');
    })
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Any ideas?

thank guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e.stopPropagation()` call should go inside the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subscribe').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#joinThanks').css('visibility', 'visible');
    })
});​
```

The syntax error this generated may have caused the odd behaviour you saw.

Comment: Thanks, although it stills disappears... I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that a form gets submitted and that somehow refreshes the page?

Comment: Yes - that will do it. The page changing will cause the flicker. To prevent that you would need to submit the form via AJAX.